# Is Windows 8 able to read partitions formatted with the ReFS filesystem?

Tags: windows-8, filesystems, windows-server-2012, refs

Does Windows 8 read ReFS? Is there a patch available or plans to add support?

My question is motivated by my desire to switch to ReFS due to the better benchmarks but I am hesitant as it may render recovery and migration difficult, as for example Linux can't read it.

My usage case is taking the HD, putting it in an enclosure, and reading it from a laptop for data recovery.

Comment: Also see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/495662/can-i-use-the-new-refs-file-system-on-windows-8).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only Windows 8 Server products support ReFS.

UPDATE, Windows 8.1 added support for ReFS

I did find the link below.

["With this MOD you can extend Windows 8 client support](http://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25561) **to format your drives** or partitions in new file system ReFS", adding read write capabilities to mounted ReFS drives.

Note: currently testing on my W8 test pc.

Note: testing done, see results below.

.

If you connect a ReFS formatted disc to Windows 8 (RTM enterprise evaluation version in my case) you will get this message, but it will mount the disk and give it a drive letter, just no access to the drive contents.

.
[image]

.

[image]

.

If you look in disk management it will show as a RAW basic disc (Disk1)

[image]

The MOD above does add ReFS read and write support to W8 (non server) (64bit W8 only)

Installation is easy, you simply copy 2 files to the correct locations and add the registry file, reboot.

.

support now shown in format utility

[image: support shown in format utility]

.

After format properties on the 300gig drive

[image: After format properties on the 300gig drive]

.

I copied and can read files on the ReFS partition now.

[image: I copied and can read files on the ReFS partition now.]

Comment: Is this mod still required when windows 8.1 client supports ReFS?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai no

Answer (score 2):

There was a blog post about [the next generation file system for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/building-the-next-generation-file-system-for-windows-refs) done a while back. In short, yes you can use ReFS on Windows 8. However, you will not be able to upgrade a drive from NTFS to ReFS without losing the data.

> **[Storage and file system](https://www.pcworld.com/article/461732/windows-8-the-official-review.html)**
>
> Windows 8 includes a new file system called ReFS (Resilient File
> System). It’s compatible with most NTFS file features, and, as the
> name suggests, it adds features to improve data integrity. Features
> left out include BitLocker, compression, and 8.3-format short
> filenames. What ReFS brings to the table is improved data verification
> and auto-correction: ReFS continually scans the file system, including
> rarely used older files, to ensure they haven’t become corrupted,
> repairing bad disk clusters and moving data as necessary. Note,
> however, that ReFS works only on secondary drives, not boot drives.
> Your boot drive will still be NTFS.

Comment: It's ONLY supported on the server OS, not on standard Windows 8.  (I first read this on that very blog post you link)

Comment: So, I can take the HD stick it into a Windows 8 comptuer and I will be able to read it?

Comment: kobaltz: From your link, "ReFS will be introduced only as part of Windows Server 8"

Comment: @Moab this stuff is a bit confusing :-)

Comment: @Misha it is supposed to be, its from Microsoft.

Comment: kobaltz: I don't trust pcworld to be the authoritative answer. Your first MS link clearly states it is for Server products only.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.bit-tech.net/news/bits/2012/01/17/microsoft-refs-file-system/1) doesn't say anything about an internal storage drive, but it does answer all other uses.

> Sadly, there are a few caveats. Unlike the move from FAT to NTFS on
>   the desktop, there will be no way to convert an existing volume to
>   ReFS without creating a new volume and copying the data manually.
>   There's no support for booting from ReFS, with NTFS being retained as
>   the file system of choice for boot drives; and you can't use ReFS on
>   removable drives.

Answer (score 0):

Support for ReFS was added in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 8.1 it is possible to enable system-wide support for ReFS (including disk manager and format tool) with the following registry key. This will allow you to format exsisting partitions to ReFS.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MiniNT]
“AllowRefsFormatOverNonmirrorVolume”=dword:00000001

[Source : My blog](http://insanedev.co.uk/enabling-refs-with-windows-8-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 works perfectly well with ReFS as long as Storage Spaces is used for mirroring. I'm using it with no problems with two 1Gb drives.